# Rails 6 API Only app generating a 422 request when crating a User & Account from same form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, postman

So I'm building a Rails 6 API, to connect to an app built with flutter, at present I'm only testing the API with Postman.

When I try to create my user & account (through the same form) my server is giving me the following error. (not too sure how proceed as its not giving a lot of information back) (I have sensored my information in the response)

Error:

```
Started POST "/api/v1/users" for ::1 at 2019-11-11 22:29:02 -0700
   (0.9ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"xxxxx@xxxxxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "f_name"=>"Me", "l_name"=>"My"}, "account_attributes"=>{"company_name"=>"Txxx Gxxx"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"xxxxxxx@xxxxxxx.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "f_name"=>"Me", "l_name"=>"My"}, "account_attributes"=>{"company_name"=>"Txxx Gxxx"}}}
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 70ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 8.5ms | Allocations: 21121)
```

And I am getting this from Postman's response body:

```
{"errors":{"email":["can't be blank"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}
```

but they are Being sent in my request??

I am sending the following through the Postman App as a JSON Body:

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "xxx@xxx.com",
        "password": "XXXX",
        "password_confirmation": "XXXX",
        "f_name": "XXXXXX",
        "l_name": "XXXXXX"
    },
    "account_attributes": {
        "company_name": "Tauren Group"
    }
}
```

I am trying to send my post request to: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users` which is what my routes show me: `POST   /api/v1/users(.:format)                                                                  api/v1/users/registrations#create {:format=>:json}`
My User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :jwt_authenticatable, jwt_revocation_strategy: JwtBlacklist
  devise :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable, :confirmable, :trackable

  belongs_to :account
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account

end
```

My Account model:

```
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
end
```

My Devise Registrations Controller:

```
    class Api::V1::Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      respond_to :json
      before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
      before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

      # GET /resource/sign_up
      def new
        #super
        build_resource({})
        resource.build_account
      end

      # POST /resource
      def create
        super

        if resource.save
          set_trial
        end
      end
      ......
  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :f_name, :l_name, account_attributes: [:company_name]])
  end

    def set_trial
      account = resource.account
      account.update_attributes!(trial_ends: 7.days.from_now)
    end
  end
```

Comment: You should probably just pass a block to super. If you look at `Devise::RegistrationsController` you can see that it yields after the record is instantiated / saved.

Comment: `super {|resource| resource.build_account }`